# implement atoi function in java

Tags: java, atoi

I am trying to implement the Atoi function in java, but it is showing me the error as:

```java
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: 
at line 67, java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString
at line 721, java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong
at line 836, java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong
at line 26, Solution.myAtoi
at line 54, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
at line 84, __Driver__.main
```

The code I implemented is as below :

```java
class Solution {
  
  public int myAtoi(String s) {
    String ans = "";
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int sign = 0;
    while (i < s.length() - 1) {
      if (s.charAt(i) == 0) {
        j++;
      }
      i++;
    }
    if (s.charAt(i) == 45) {
      sign = -1;
    } else {
      sign = +1;
    }
    i++;
    j++;
    while (i < s.length() - 1) {
      if (s.charAt(i) >= 48 && s.charAt(i) <= 57) {
        ans = ans + s.charAt(i);
      }
    }
    long x = Long.parseLong(ans);
    if (sign == (-1)) {
      x = x * (-1);
    }
    int ret = (int) x;
    return ret;
  }
}
```

Can anyone point out the error in the code?

Comment: `ans` is empty; `i == s.length()` when the second `while` loop is executed, so nothing gets added to `ans` (the error message *includes* the wrong string, in this case empty) - maybe better use `for` loops instead of `while` (or at least reset the value of `i` before starting the second `while` loop) -- you should use a debugger to see what exactly is happening

Comment: The while loop never executes because i is equal to s.length(). A debugger or some judicious println calls will assist.

Comment: Don’t use “magic numbers” like `48`, `57`, or `45` when you can use constants expressing the intent, i.e. `'0'`, `'9'`, or `'-'`. Further, what is `s.charAt(i)==0` supposed to test? Java Strings usually don’t contain zero codepoints. And where’s the sense in trying to implement a string to number parsing method yourself, when you end up calling `Long.parseLong(ans)` which does already the entire job of parsing a string to number?

Comment: I implemented this code in the leetcode : https://leetcode.com/problems/string-to-integer-atoi/. But the code gave me error, also the first while loop checked for spaces, then I checked for the sign and then the second while loop was implemented to find the number.

Comment: A zero codepoint is not a space. White-space are characters like `' '` or `'\t'` (`32` resp. `9` but as said, use the character constants rather than the numbers). Even better is using `Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))`. The standard idiom for decimal number parsing is: 1. Start with a value of zero 2. For each digit, multiple the current value by ten and add the digit’s numeric value. This allows you to also stop the loop when detecting that the value space is exceeded, as that’s required by the task.

Comment: @closevoters Why closing with need debugging details? There is expected output (string parsed to int), actual result (exception) and minimal, reproducible example (copy/pasting the code is enough to reproduce the issue). All the information needed for a debugging question is available.

Comment: @Chaosfire the input is not in the question?

Comment: @aled It's reproducible for **any** input.

Comment: BTW, AFAIK, in C and similar, strings are terminated by a ZERO character - unlike in Java where we have a `length` attribute. Not sure if that is the reason for posted code to check for ZERO; hard to say since `j` is never really used